# javascript pass checkbox element keep checked status

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox

I'm having a dialog pop up to let user input some information, upon dialog confirmed, the result is added to the parent pages form:

```
var inputs = element.getElementsByTagName('input');
while(inputs.length > 0) 
form.appendChild(inputs[0]);
```

It works for other inputs, except for checkboxes, it looks like the "checked" option wasn't passed. Is there anyway to keep the status for these checkboxes?

Comment: it should work can you show us a fiddle ?

Comment: ah! my bad! it did work! there was something wrong with my java end